# Compare single property within Two Lists of Different Classes

Tags: c#, linq

I have been reading about how to do this for the last 2 days and I still am at a loss of understanding how to do it.

**Goal:**
Compare list of "existing Database Motors" to list of "New Excel Motors" by comparing the name property of each list only. I do not want to compare any of the other properities. Return a list of objects that are unique to only "existing Database Motors".

This is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

Custom Classes:

```
public class motor_Excel
{
    public string MotorName; //the field I need to be able to compare with motor_Database.iName
    public string MotorVoltage;
    public double MotorHP;
}

public class motor_Database
{
    public int iID;
    public string iName; //the field I need to be able to compare with motor_Excel.MotorName
    public int iCircuit;
}
```

Make lists of those custom classes:

```
List<motor_Database> equipList_EX = ReadDatabase(DBpath.txt); //create new custom obj list of from database
List<motor_Excel> equipList_Update = ReadExcel(Excelpath.txt); //create new custom obj list of from excel
```

I would like to return something like this (I know that this wont work, ".Except" only takes generics):

```
List<motor_Database> result = equipList_EX.iName.Except(equipList_Update.MotorName)
```

---

I believe that I have 4 options:

Option 1: Use LINQ "Where:
Option 2: Use extension method
Option 3: Linq Except with custom IEqualityComparer
Option 4: Enumerable.SequenceEqual( list1, list2)

---

I have been having SO much trouble with this. Im struggling to learn how the LINQ, Except, IEqualityCompare, etc work. Im starting to feel really dumb, I've never felt so incapable before. Im new to C#, and **Im struggling to even comprehend the MS.documentation on this stuff**. I can't make any sense of how to read the [Enumerable.Except Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-except-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0)))) docs. The API documentation is like nothing I have experienced before... If you have recommendations on how I can learn how to read documentation for these classes/methods I would appreciate it.

Please, explain at fundamental levels why except wont work. Im so confused.

Comment: What you posted won't even compile. `List<>` has no `iName` property. Post a clear explanation of the problem what you expect, what you tried, what you got. That doesn't mean write in a rigid formalized form. `Except` applies to lists/collections of the same stuff. The same way SQL's EXCEPT does and set theory's EXCEPT does.

Comment: In any case, if you want to find the difference between existing and new motors, why did you create two unrelated classes? You should have just a `Motor` class, a `List<Motor> db_Motors` and a `List<Motor> new_Motors`. `Except` and `ExceptBy` will work just fine in that case

Comment: If you only want to check names, you don't even need a list of new Motor objects, just a list of the names ie `List<string>`. You don't need Except in that case, `old.Where(motor=>!new_Names.Contains(motor.Name))` is enough. If `new_Names` is a HashSet<string>` lookups will be far faster than a `List<string>`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to read data from 2 different locations that store motor data in different formats. Then determine which motors in the "new" are already in the existing list. Remove them before converting the "uniquely new" motors to the database format and storing them.

Comment: That's what you wrote at the top of the question. The rest is how you thought the answer would look like. That's not a set difference operation. You wouldn't be able to use EXCEPT in SQL for this either. Set operations only work with items of the same type.

Comment: In both set and relational theory you'd have to project different types into the same "shape". In SQL and LINQ that's done with `SELECT`. Once the sets have the same shape you can use set operations. In this case though, there are easier and quicker options

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're confused is because you're looking at the API reference, not [LINQ's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/). You'd have the same problem with any language, any API.

The assignment text says nothing about multiple classes:

> Compare list of "existing Database Motors" to list of "New Excel Motors" by comparing the name property of each list only.

If you were comparing Motor objects you'd only need a single `Motor` class. In this case though you're comparing only names. You're checking to find the Motor objects whose names don't appear in a List of new motor names.

[Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-6.0) isn't useful here. As the description says :

> Produces the set difference of two sequences.

This isn't idle wording. Just like SQL's `EXCEPT` the type/shape of the two sets must be the same. That's why the method only works with items of the same *type*.

What you want can be done using `Where` and `List<string>.Contains`

```
List<Motor> motors=ReadDatabase(DBpath.txt); 
List<string> new_names=ReadExcel(...);

var old_motors=motors.Where(m=>!new_names.Contains(m.Name))
                     .ToList();
```

You can speed this up if you use a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0)

```
...
var names_set=new HashSet<string>(new_names);
var old_motors=motors.Where(m=>!names_set.Contains(m.Name))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: I didnt realize I was looking at the wrong documentation. Thank you.
I ended up getting it to work using:  
List<motor_Database> delete = equipList_EX.Where(ex => !motorsNew.Select(x => x.MotorName).Contains(ex.EQU_CALLOUT)).ToList();  
Also  
List<motor_Database> delete = equipList_EX.Where(ex => !motorNew.Select(x => x.MotorName).Contains(ex.EQU_CALLOUT)).ToList();

Comment: @BrandonG that's very expensive because it executes the inner query for every outer item. You cold replace this with `motorsNew.Any(x=>x.MotorName)` but that's no better than `List.Contains` and definitely worse than `HashSet.Contains`. In fact, since it loads properties that aren't needed, it ends up eating more RAM than a `List<string>`

Comment: If you really have to load the Excel items, you can use `var names=motorsNew.Select(x=>x.MotorName).ToHashSet();` to build a HashSet from the names. `names` acts as an index in this case

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, couldn't you just filter the database motors by comparing each one's name to the list of excel motor names, and return the entries that don't have a match?

```
List<motor_Database> dbMotors = ReadDatabase(DBpath.txt); 
List<motor_Excel> xlMotors = ReadExcel(Excelpath.txt);

List<motor_Database> uniqueDbMotors = dbMotors
  .Where(dbMotor => xlMotors.All(xlMotor => xlMotor.MotorName != dbMotor.iName))
  .ToList();
```

Also, in you list of "options", you left out using a simple `for` loop. The above code could be written as:

```
var uniqueDbMotors = new List<motor_Database>();

foreach(var dbMotor in dbMotors)
{
    var foundMatch = false;

    foreach (var xlMotor in xlMotors)
    {
        if (dbMotor.iName == xlMotor.MotorName)
        {
            foundMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!foundMatch) uniqueDbMotors.Add(dbMotor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "LEFT JOIN" for such task:

```cs
List<motor_Database> result = 
    (from ex in equipList_EX
    join up in equipList_Update on ex.iName equals up.MotorName into gj
    from up in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where up == null
    select ex).ToList();
```